# How to configure IIS and the client in two different virtual machines

Tags: iis, tomcat, isapi, isapi-filters

My question is about the connection between IIS (ISAPI Filter) and an application.
I have to Configure IIS 7.5 and Tomcat Connector ISAPI Filter on Windows Server 2019
I want to configure IIS in a virtual machine and I will have the tomcat app in another machine .
Is the link between them would be with dns or another configuration?
Thank you

Comment: You will have to edit the question to describe explicitly what kind of ISAPI filter you were referring to and what kind of application. ISAPI does allow a lot to be done in a filter like connecting to another machine, so that you can build things like reverse proxy.

Comment: I edit my question. Hope it's a little bit clear now. But I don't know if your solution about the reverse proxy is good. I want to know if the connection will be between IIS and a tomcat in different machines or it will be between the machines ?
"attach the filter to a server, which handles the connection IIS -> Tomcat in another server)"

Comment: So by typing so much, your ultimate goal is just to host Java web apps via IIS. Then that's a rather strange decision you want to have IIS and Tomcat on different machines and you will have to explain why that's better than having them on the same machine and use something like HttpPlatformHandler to glue them. Forget about the Tomcat Connector ISAPI, which for decades brings nightmares to users.

Comment: I already have them both on the same machine . but in the project , I have another task that I should separate the app from iis. 
in the situation that they are in the same machine . there is isapi filtre who connect them. But in two differents environnements , would isapi filter do the same work?

Comment: Then go to Tomcat docs and learn from step 6 in "Configuring the ISAPI Redirector" https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html that you can specify either local or remote Tomcat servers. And if you want some exclusive Microsoft support, you should use IIS+ARR as reverse proxy instead.